# get both values from a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've got a Dataset in tensorflow which returns tuples because it is designed to be used to create features and labels. How can I iterate over it in python and extract these tuples?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

def generator():
    index = 0
    while True:
        feature = np.ones([1,4]) * index
        label = feature[0:1,0:2]
        print('yielding:', feature, label)
        yield feature, label
        index +=1


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator=generator,
    output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64),
    output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([1,4]),tf.TensorShape([1,2])),
)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
data = iterator.get_next()

print(data[0].eval(session=sess))
print(data[1].eval(session=sess))
print(data[0].eval(session=sess))
print(data[1].eval(session=sess))
```

output:

```
yielding: [[0. 0. 0. 0.]] [[0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]]
yielding: [[1. 1. 1. 1.]] [[1. 1.]]
[[1. 1.]]
yielding: [[2. 2. 2. 2.]] [[2. 2.]]
[[2. 2. 2. 2.]]
yielding: [[3. 3. 3. 3.]] [[3. 3.]]
[[3. 3.]]
```

The problem is, that the iterator steps each time I evaluate one of the data elements. But I'm unable to get the values for `data[0]` and `data[1]` that correspond to the same step.

I'm looking for something like `eval_tuple(data)` which would return `([[2. 2. 2. 2.]] [[2. 2.]])`.

Note: I'm not fixated on evaluating the `data` tuple I've created in the code above. The goal is to extract matching feature-label pairs from the `dataset` object.

Comment: `sess.run(data)`

Comment: @user1735003 : yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!